# comparing two estimates by the law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, parameter-estimation, law-of-large-numbers

I would like to make sure that I have enough data to show that the estimate of the mean of a fair dice and a dice with and exchanged dot for two dots (2,2,3,4,5,6) are significantly different. Is there a standardized way?

[image: Estimate (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lawoflargenumbers.svg)]

Comment: You want a test to distinguish the two and a power analysis to demonstrate your sample size is sufficiently like to reject the hypothesis that they are the same using that test

Comment: So that means a t-test and a power analysis? Would you provide please more details or references?